# Find all A^x in a given range

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

I need to find all monomials in the form A<sup>X</sup> that when evaluated falls within a range from `m` to `n`. It is safe to say that the base `A` is greater than 1, the power `X` is greater than 2, and only integers need to be used.  For example, in the range 50 to 100, the solutions would be:

```
2^6
3^4
4^3
```

My first attempt to solve this was to brute force all combinations of `A` and `X` that make "sense."  However this becomes too slow when used for very large numbers in a big range since these solutions are used in part of much more intensive processing. Here is the code:

```
def monoSearch(min, max):
    base = 2
    power = 3

    while 1:
        while base**power < max:
            if base**power > min:
                print "Found " + repr(base) + "^" + repr(power) + "   = " + repr(base**power)    
            power = power + 1
        base = base + 1
        power = 3
        if base**power > max:
            break
```

I could remove one `base**power` by saving the value in a temporary variable but I don't think that would make a drastic effect.  I also wondered if using logarithms would be better or if there was a closed form expression for this.  I am open to any optimizations or alternatives to finding the solutions.

Comment: Depending on the relative values of m, n and X, it might be quicker to find the smallest such A^X, then the largest. Edit: sorry, you want every *combination* of A and X - more thinking required...

Comment: I'm fairly certain that, similar to the sum version of this problem,  it's in NP.  That would be the knapsack problem, BTW.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't search; consider the endpoints.

For example, all the solutions with `x == 3` are such that `a` is between the cube root of `m` and the cube root of `n`. So calculate those cube roots and use the range of integers in between. Since `a` is at least 2, the maximum `x` is log base 2 of `n`, so that's how you know when to stop.

```
from math import log, ceil, floor

def monoSearch(low, high):
    max_power = int(floor(log(high) / log(2)))
    for power in range(3, max_power + 1):
        min_base = low ** (1.0 / power)
        max_base = high ** (1.0 / power)
        for base in range(int(ceil(min_base)), int(floor(max_base)) + 1):
            yield '%s ^ %s' % (base, power)

print '\n'.join(monoSearch(42, 1000000))
```

This may miss a couple of values due to floating-point imprecision, unfortunately.

Comment: I timed it.  It's over 2 times faster than the original with larger numbers.  (Much faster than mine, I might add.)

Comment: On my test case, my method took 39.49 seconds... yours took 0.91 seconds :) Thank you sir.

Comment: If you really need the extra values, you could add an explicit check if `max_base + 1` works (by re-performing the exponentiation), and unconditionally looping up to `max_power + 2` should be safe.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I compared our methods again with an actual case and my method took 5 minutes 29 seconds.  Yours took 9 seconds.

Answer (score 7):

Using the fact that log(x) is an increasing function:

`m <= a^x <= n` if and only if `log(m) <= x * log(a) <= log(n)`

Then finding numbers `x`, `log(a)` whose product lies within this transformed interval will be much easier.

Comment: I knew log would be a better route, but wouldn't I still have to search through a large combination of x and log(a)?

Comment: I don't think you need to search, you should be able to solve it easily in the plane

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize this using multiple binary searches. Note the following for any given base:

- Once you reach a power such that `base**power` exceeds `min` all powers `p >= power` satisfy `base**p >= min` -> You can binary search for the minimum power
- An analogous argument proves that you can binary search for the maximum power such that `base**power <= max`
- To find the maximum base such that `base**power <= max` for any `power >= 3`, you can also apply binary search

Now, you can use logarithms as @wim said, but that requires that the numbers you're working with are representable by floats, whereas using binary searches work as long as you have arbitrary precision integer arithmetic (and Python does).

Answer (score 1):

You can find the lower and upper bound for working exponents using logarithms.  It basically finds the smallest exponent, and largest exponent that fit between m and n, and creates a range for that.  If there's any part in particular that's confusing (I know I nested a lot of functions) just ask.

```
from math import log, ceil, floor, sqrt

def monoSearch(m, n):
    for base in range(2, int(ceil(n**.34))):
        m_pow = max(int(ceil(log(m, base))), 3)
        n_pow = int(ceil(log(n, base)))

        pows = range(m_pow, n_pow)
        for p in pows:
            print "Found {}^{}  = {}".format(base, p, base**p)
```

Comment: Oops, I incorrectly put a comment on your answer rather than Karl's.  While your method is better than mine, you're right that Karl's is even better than yours.  Thank you for your solution though!